# Why can I not install haskell Slides package?

Tags: haskell, cabal

Attempting to install Haskell's [Slides](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Slides) package, I run into cabal hell:

```
$ cabal update && cabal install slides
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: Slides-0.1.0.8 (user goal)
next goal: base (dependency of Slides-0.1.0.8)
rejecting: base-4.9.0.0/installed-4.9... (conflict: Slides => base>=4.8 &&
<4.9)
rejecting: base-4.9.0.0, base-4.8.2.0, base-4.8.1.0, base-4.8.0.0,
base-4.7.0.2, base-4.7.0.1, base-4.7.0.0, base-4.6.0.1, base-4.6.0.0,
base-4.5.1.0, base-4.5.0.0, base-4.4.1.0, base-4.4.0.0, base-4.3.1.0,
base-4.3.0.0, base-4.2.0.2, base-4.2.0.1, base-4.2.0.0, base-4.1.0.0,
base-4.0.0.0, base-3.0.3.2, base-3.0.3.1 (constraint from non-upgradeable
package requires installed instance)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
```

I reset my packages by running:

```
$ rm -rf ~/.ghc ~/.cabal
```

per the instructions [here](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/simonmichael/how-to-cabal-install#could-not-resolve-dependencies--cabal-hell), but still get that same error. Not sure what to try next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slides library 0.1.0.8 (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Slides) has not been updated to work with GHC versions > 7.10.  This is apparent from the base restriction `base < 4.9` since GHC 8 uses base 4.9.

You can:

- File an issue with the maintainer, who should fix this and upload a new version.
- `cabal unpack slides` then `cd slides*` and edit `slides.cabal` changing `< 4.9` to `< 4.10` then `cabal install`.  That is usually all that is required, but not always so you might see a new set of compilation errors.

Comment: I contacted the maintainer who updated the package. Thanks!